# Unable to enter symbols through number keyboard on Android

Tags: android, input, keyboard, android-edittext, symbols

I am launching a number keyboard but the symbols '-', '.' etc. are not working.

```
public class WebEditText extends EditText

mWebEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
webEditTextPanel.addView(mWebEditText, lp);
mWebEditText.requestFocus(); 
imm.showSoftInput(mWebEditText, 0);
```

Anything that I'm missing here? The dispatchKeyEvent doesn't get invoked for the symbols, however for the numbers it gets invoked and works fine.

[image: Number keyboard]

Answer (score 1):

`InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` limits your input to just numbers. You'll want to use a different InputType constant, like `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`, which will still give you the numbers keyboard.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_PHONE

i.e.

```
mWebEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Comment: Same result as TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER, the symbols are not getting accepted. I'm using Android 2.3.4

Comment: I tried both TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and TYPE_CLASS_PHONE on my 2.3.3 emulator. TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER gave me the same result as you (no special characters), but TYPE_CLASS_PHONE worked. Can you try yours on an emulator, and if it works, delete the version on your device and try again?